# can we use same value in st-search in different html?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm trying to search my data using st-search. I am Using Smart tables.This is my code.

```
<input st-search="id" 
    ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && function()" 
    class="form-control" type="search"/>
```

The same code i'm using in different html,when i try to change the value in st-search input box the same value get's changed in other html where ever i uses that code.I'm not using ng-model.

can anyone help me?